# Подсветка синтаксиса c++-cli

Tags: дефект, поддержка, статус-завершено

Нужно добавить языку [c++-cli](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b-cli/info) соответствие с `lang-cpp` (как это сделано, например, для [c++11](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b11/info)), чтобы работала подсветка синтаксиса.